# SearchView widget using HoloEverywhere library doesn't show on Android 2.3.4

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere

I want to implement a SearchView on the ActionBar of one of my activities. I'm using HoloEverywhere, which includes the new AppCompat library and uses it as a base. My Activity, then, extends org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity, which is an extension of some version of ActionBarActivity. I can add the icon on the action bar and it looks ok en all the devices and emulators I use. This is how the Search action looks like on an Android 2.2 emulator:

[image: The ActionBar on Android 2.2 before the icon is pressed]

So far so good. When I press the magnifier icon, the behavior is the expected on an Android 4.1.1 Genymotion instance, and also on the Android 2.2 emulator:

[image: This is how the search edit text looks like]

But, in my Android 2.3.4 phone, this is what I get:

[image: The action icon disappears, but there is nothing there]

The action icon and the action bar title disappear, but there is nothing there. And the soft keyboard opens, just like if there is something there, but I can't see it.

This is my `onCreateOptionsMenu` method:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        if (searchView != null) {
           searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        }

        ) );

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

I debugged it an searchView is never `null` --a problem that seems to be common when there is something wrong on the menu XML, but this is not the case. By the way, this is how my menu.xml looks like:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/activity_main_search"
          android:showAsAction="always"
          android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    />
</menu>
```

I used the "android:" namespace because of [this](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/issues/692). And as it works properly on the Android 2.2 emulator, it seems ok.

Also, another weird thing: if I add the line

```
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

on the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method, then the resulting "always open" field looks the same on all the devices/emulators. See, this is how non-iconified SearchView looks on the Android 2.3.4 phone:

[image: This is how the non-iconified SearchView looks on the Android 2.3.4 phone]

And this is how it looks on the Android 4.1.1 Genymotion image:

[image: And this is how it looks on the Android 4.1.1 Genymotion image]

Anyone has a hint on how can I fix this? I've searched around and found many questions related to SearchView on AppCompat and HoloEverywhere, but I can't find a way to make the search field work properly on this Android 2.3.4 device.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found it. It seems like the time I used to create the question was all I needed to clear my mind.

I added this line on the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method:

```
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(searchItem, 
             MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | 
             MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
```

And now the SearchView works and looks the same on all the devices, but the little `X` to erase the content (if any) and close the input is missing in all of them until the user types. To close the search field and get to the normal ActionBar you need to use the back button. Oh well, the UX/UI designer should have to live with it... :P